# How do I get the Ralink wireless controller working on an HP Envy 7212nr?

Tags: wireless, ralink

The output of `lshw -C network` reads as follows:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED     

   description: Network controller

    product: Ralink corp.
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0

       resources: memory:73510000-7351ffff

*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: a0:b3:cc:4d:66:1a
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation





configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:73404000-73404fff memory:73400000-73403fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.

~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:b3:cc:4d:66:1a  
          inet addr:192.168.1.9  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a2b3:ccff:fe4d:661a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16815 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17332774 (17.3 MB)  TX bytes:2545565 (2.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:399550 (399.5 KB)  TX bytes:399550 (399.5 KB)
~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        A0:B3:CC:4D:66:1A

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.9
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1


~$ lspci -nn
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3290]
0a:00.1 Bluetooth [0d11]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3298]
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
```

0a:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 3290
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 18ec
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at 73510000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities:

0a:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. Device 3298
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 18ec
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at 73500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities:

I can use the wired Internet but cannot see any of the wireless in the menu, I am new to Ubuntu so please help!

Comment: What happens when you run `ifconfig` or `nm-tool`? Do you see the device wlan0 and any wireless networks?

Comment: lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3341 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3341 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:333812 (333.8 KB)  TX bytes:333812 (333.8 KB)

Comment: We need more details about your Ralink wireless. What are the details from: lspci -nn. The Ralink wireless only, please.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `lspci -v | grep -iA 10 'network'` and the output of `lsmod`. Output of `iwconfig` would help too.

Comment: sorry, im new to this, how do i add the output of those commands to the question?

Comment: @raviteja Click on the the link that says "edit." It's right at the end of the question.